# Is there a term for characters that appear from ios logs like `\M-C\M-6` or `\134`

Tags: go, types, control-characters

I'm trying to figure out the term for these types of characters:

> \M-C\M-6 (corresponds to german "ö")
>
> \M-C\M-$ (corresponds to german "ä")
>
> \M-C\M^_ (corresponds to german "ß")

I want to know the term for these outputs so that I can easily convert them into the utf-8 character they actually are in golang instead of creating a mapping of each I come across.

What is the term for these? unicode? What would be the best way to convert these "characters" to their actual human readable character in golang?

Answer (score 1):

It is the [vis](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=vis&sektion=3) encoding of UTF-8 encoded text.

Here's an example:

The UTF-8 encoding of the rune `ö` in bytes is `[0303, 0266]`.

vis encodes the byte `0303` as the bytes `\M-C` and the byte `0266` as the bytes `\M-6`.

Putting the two levels of encoding together, the rune `ö` is encoded as the bytes `\M-C\M-6`.

You can either write an decoder using the documentation on the [man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=vis&sektion=3) or search for a decoding package.  The Go standard library does not include such a decoder.

Comment: The [govis](https://godoc.org/github.com/cyphar/govis) package may be helpful in decoding vis.  I found the package by searching for "vis golang". I make no claims about the suitability of the package.